# Get time zones using a specific offset for a given moment, in Java

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, timezone-offset

I know:

- An offset is merely a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead/behind the temporal meridian of UTC.
- A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a specific region, as determined by their politicians.

So for any moment, a particular time zone is using one offset while in another moment that same time zone may be using a different offset.

And, of course, any number of time zones may share the same offset at any one point in time.

Is there a way to obtain a list of time zones using a particular offset at a particular moment?

Answer (score 1):

### tl;dr

```java
Instant now = Instant.now ( );
ZoneOffset offsetTarget = ZoneOffset.ofHours ( -4 );  // -04:00

List < ZoneId > zoneIdsWithTargetOffset =
        ZoneId
                .getAvailableZoneIds ( )  // Returns List<String>, not List<ZoneId>. Text is in format: Continent/Region.
                .stream ( )
                .map ( ZoneId :: of )     // Make a `ZoneId` object of each `String` zone name, each Continent/Region. 
                .filter (
                        ( ZoneId zoneId ) -> zoneId.getRules ( ).getOffset ( now ).equals ( offsetTarget )  // Get the offset in effect for that zone at that moment. See if that offset matches our target offset. 
                )
                .toList ()                // Collect `ZoneId` objects.
;
```

### Details

Yes, you can get such a list in Java 8+ using the *java.time* classes.

The `ZoneId` class represents each time zone, with a name in the format of `Continent/Region`. The rules in use by each time zone are contained in a `ZoneRules` object.

The `ZoneOffset` class represents a mere offset.

The `Instant` class represents a moment, a specific point on the time line, as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC. To get the current moment, call `Instant.now()`.

We can interrogate the zone rules for the offset in use by a zone at any particular moment. This means getting a `ZoneId` by its name, asking for its rules, and the passing an `Instant` to the `getOffset` method of the rules object.

```java
final Instant now = Instant.now ( );
final ZoneOffset offsetTarget = ZoneOffset.ofHours ( -4 );  // -04:00

final Set < String > zoneNames = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds ( );
final Collection < ZoneId > zoneIdsWithTargetOffset = new ArrayList <> ( );
for ( String zoneName : zoneNames )
{
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( zoneName );
    ZoneRules rules = zoneId.getRules ( );
    ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset ( now );
    if ( offset.equals ( offsetTarget ) )
    {
        zoneIdsWithTargetOffset.add ( zoneId );
    }
}
System.out.println ( "At " + now + ", " + zoneIdsWithTargetOffset.size ( ) + " zones have an offset of " + offsetTarget + " ➡️ " + zoneIdsWithTargetOffset ); // ️
```

See this [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/tqk9lo).

> At 2023-11-21T21:59:37.279097Z, 43 zones have an offset of -04:00 ➡️ [America/Cuiaba, America/Marigot, Canada/Atlantic, Etc/GMT+4, America/Manaus, America/St_Thomas, America/Anguilla, America/Barbados, America/Curacao, America/Guyana, America/Martinique, America/Puerto_Rico, America/Port_of_Spain, SystemV/AST4, America/Kralendijk, America/Antigua, America/Moncton, America/St_Vincent, America/Dominica, Atlantic/Bermuda, Brazil/West, America/Aruba, America/Halifax, America/La_Paz, America/Blanc-Sablon, America/Santo_Domingo, America/Glace_Bay, America/St_Barthelemy, America/St_Lucia, America/Montserrat, America/Lower_Princes, America/Thule, America/Tortola, America/Porto_Velho, America/Campo_Grande, America/Goose_Bay, America/Virgin, America/Boa_Vista, America/Grenada, America/St_Kitts, America/Caracas, America/Guadeloupe, SystemV/AST4ADT]

**Beware:** Politicians frequently change the rules of the time zone(s) within their jurisdiction. They sometimes make those changes with an alarming lack of forewarning. Be sure the [tzdata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) within your JVM is current for the time zones of interest to you. **You may need to update the tzdata** yourself, as new versions arrive faster than updates to Java.